# AJAX list update, get new elements and count

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this HTML list

```
<ul id='usernameList'>
    <li class='username'>John</li>
    <li class='username'>Mark</li>
</ul>
```

and a form to add new names via AJAX, multiple add separated by commas. The response is a list with the names

```
[{name:David, newUser:yes}, {name:Sara, newUser:yes}, {name:Mark, newUser:no}]
```

I'm trying to insert this names sorted alphabetically in the list, like this example https://jsfiddle.net/VQu3S/7/

This is my AJAX submit

```
var form = $('#formUsername');
form.submit(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        //
    },
    success: function (data) {

        var listUsernames = $('#usernameList');
        var numUsernames = listUsernames.children().length;

        $.each(data, function(i, user) {
            if(user.newUser == "yes"){

                var htmlUser = "<li class='username'>" + user.name + "</li>";
                var added = false;

                $(".username", listUsernames).each(function(){
                    if ($(this).text() > user.name) {
                        $(htmlUser).insertBefore($(this));
                        added = true;
                    }

                });

                if(!added)
                    $(htmlUser).appendTo($(listUsernames));

            }

            // HERE I DO alert('numUsernames')
            // I get the same number of users before sending form

            // How can I update here the value of listUsernames and numUsernames?
        });



    }
});
return false;
});
```

My question is, how I can update the value of `listUsernames` and `numUsernames` after adding an item?

Comment: `if ($(this).text() > user.name) {` You know you're comparing strings right ?

Comment: Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vzu6x/1/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update `numUsernames` at that point.

Add this where your comments are:

```
numUsernames = listUsernames.children().length;
```

`listUsernames` already has the updated children, as it's a reference to the parent element.

Edit: Re: your comment below:

This should probably work:

```
$(".username", listUsernames).each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() > user.name) {
        $(htmlUser).insertBefore($(this));
        added = true;
        return false; // stop `.each` loop.
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry accidentally delete the comment, yes that found.. i add `numUsernames = listUsernames.children().length;` and i get the new number of elements in the list.. but for example in a empty list if i add 'Mickey' and later i add 'David'.. It insert 'David' at the end, not in sorted alphabetically. But if i add 'mickey' i refresh the page and i add 'david', it insert sorted alphabetically first, david and second myckey

Comment: thanks, it works!! There is no problem.. is because i do some changes and in the var htmlUser i had forgotten put the class='username'

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need a double jQuery wrapping:

```
$(htmlUser).appendTo($(listUsernames));
```

`listUsernames` is already a jQuery object, so try:

```
$(htmlUser).appendTo(listUsernames);
```

And after every adding, you can update the `numUsernames` variable with:

```
numUsernames = listUsernames.children().length;
```

but this is not necessary because you can always access `listUsernames.children().length` in the `success` handler.

Comment: Even though re-extending it is unnecessary, removing it is unlikely to make any difference i'd think..

Answer (score 0):

I update your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VQu3S/187/)

```
var listUsernames = $('#usernameList');
var numUsernames = listUsernames.children().length;
 var data = [{name:'David', newUser:'yes'}, {name:'Sara', newUser:'yes'}, {name:'Mark', newUser:'no'}]
$.each(data, function(i, user) {
    if(user.newUser == "yes"){

        var htmlUser = "<li class='username'>" + user.name + "</li>";
        var added = false;

        $(".ingredient", listUsernames).each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() > user.name) {
                $(htmlUser).insertBefore($(this));
                added = true;
            }

        });

        if(!added)
            $(htmlUser).appendTo($(listUsernames));

    }

    // HERE I DO alert('numUsernames')
    // I get the same number of users before sending form

    // How can I update here the value of listUsernames and numUsernames?
});
```